# Error in that.vect.push_back(0) and that.vect.begin() in overloading "+" orerator in C++

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, vector

```
class Polinom {
     public:
        std::vector<double> vect;
        Polinom operator +(const Polinom &that) {
            if (this->vect.size() > that.vect.size()) {
                for (int i = that.vect.size(); i < this->vect.size(); i++)
                    that.vect.push_back(0);//here
            }
            else if (that.vect.size() > this->vect.size()) {
                for (int i = this->vect.size(); i < that.vect.size(); i++)
                    this->vect.push_back(0);
            }
            std::vector<double> sum;
            std::vector<double>::iterator i2 = that.vect.begin();//here
            for (std::vector<double>::iterator i1 = this->vect.begin(); i1 != this->vect.end(); ++i1)
                sum.push_back(*i2++ + *i1);
            return sum;
        }
        Polinom();
        Polinom(std::vector<double> vect) {
            this->vect = vect;
        }
        ~Polinom();
};
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1087   no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=double, _Alloc=std::allocator]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)

Comment: Why are you attempting to push new values in a const vector?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> Polinom operator +(const Polinom &that) {
>                    ^^^^^
> ```

`that` is a const reference.

> ```
> that.vect.push_back(0);//here
> ```

Since `that` is const, so are member access expressions through that reference. Thus `that.vect` is a const expression.

`push_back` is a non-const member function. It modifies the vector. The function cannot be called on const vectors.

> ```
> std::vector<double>::iterator i2 = that.vect.begin();//here
> ```

`std::vector<T>::begin() const` returns a `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`. It is not implicitly convertible to `std::vector<T>::iterator`

Solution 1: Don't attempt to push elements into const vectors.

Solution 2: Use a non-const reference when you intend to modify the referred object.

In this case, solution 1. seems to be more sensible. Modifying operands of `operator+` would be counter intuitive. Furthermore, you should probably make the function const qualified, and avoid modifying `this`, for the same reason.

Answer (score 4):

`That` is constant, so you can't pushback into it. Not sure what you want to do there. Figure out if you want to modify `that` or not, and pass either a `&` or a `const&`.

And `that` is constant, you can't get an `iterator`, only a `const_iterator` (`auto` would capture it properly).

Comment: *"Not sure what you want to do there."* This is a variation on a common mistake. The common mistake is trying to implement `operator+` but instead implementing `operator+=`. Except in this case, the operators roles are reversed.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The OP is trying to left pad his multiple precision numbers with zeros so they are equal length, so the subsequent addition is easier to implement. The solution would be to implement a function that takes a 'digit' from the number irrespective of length.

Comment: @john Hmm, hadn't noticed that OP was actually trying to modify both `vect`.